# Hover on sub menu item when cursor is over it

Tags: css, menu, hover

I know it's a beginner question but I'm failing on each attempt. I am trying to make my submenu items glow (using hover) when I point the cursor over it but I am unable to do it.

Here's my CSS code:

```
 /* submenu */

.main-menu li ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.main-menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 101%;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: #333;
  padding: 0.4em 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 155px;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-menu ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin-top: -1px;

}

.main-menu ul li a {
    line-height: 23px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.main-menu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0%;
}

 .main-menu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the w3 school's documentation on the hover state:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

From the documentation:

> Definition and Usage   The :hover selector is used to select elements
>   when you mouse over them.   Tip: The :hover selector can be used on
>   all elements, not only on links.   Tip: Use the :link selector to
>   style links to unvisited pages, the :visited selector to style links
>   to visited pages, and the :active selector to style the active link.
>   Note: :hover MUST come after :link and :visited (if they are present)
>   in the CSS definition, in order to be effective!